# Install other distro kernal in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, kernel, asus, battery, function-keys

I have latest asus FX553VD laptop, it came with ENDLESS OS. Endless os perform very well with my laptop...like battery and all function keys working very good.

Now, I am regular user of UBUNTU. my laptop battery drain very fast with ubuntu kernal and also function/multimedia keys are not working properly. So, I need to install ENDLESS OS kernel in UBUNTU. So, I guess, it will help me.

Please tell me, In which way I can achieve this things. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently installed Ubuntu on a very new, recently released ASUS ROG mobo machine.  Like you, there were a number of things that didn't work.  And several that still don't work.

After a lot of work and research to cherry pick solutions to each problem, it became apparent that patience is the name of the game.

The Ubuntu Team is very active and seems to get new hardware and products implemented into the Ubuntu kernel fairly quickly.  Perhaps a Ubuntu version that is on a quicker release cycle than LTS might implement the features you need sooner.

Comment: Ya, I know that bcs i m using ubuntu from very beginning/aprox 6 yeas . I can wait, But i need to try from my side.... anyway, Thanks.